# replace padding in base64 encoding in python 3

Tags: python, string, byte, encode

```
import base64
s = "05052020"
```

python2.7

```
base64.b64encode(s)
```

output is string `'MDUwNTIwMjA='`

python 3.7

```
base64.b64encode(b"05052020")
```

output is bytes

```
b'MDUwNTIwMjA='
```

I want to replace = with "a"

```
s = str(base64.b64encode(b"05052020"))[2:-1]
s = s.replace("=", "a")
```

I realise it is dirty way so how can I do it better?

EDIT:
expected result:

Python code 3 output string with replaced padding

Comment: What is the expected result (string or bytes)? And do you want code compatible Python2 and Python 3?

Comment: code in Python3 and output shall be string with replaced padding.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, a byte string supports almost the same methods as a unicode string (except for `encode`/`decode`). So you can just do:

```
s = base64.b64encode(b"05052020").replace(b'=', b'a')
```

to get the `b'MDUwNTIwMjAa'` byte string.

If you want an unicode string, just decode it:

```
s = base64.b64encode(b"05052020").replace(b'=', b'a').decode()
```

will give `'MDUwNTIwMjAa'` as a plain (unicode) Python 3 string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to replace the padding? If the `=` character breaks something, just remove them, these characters contain no information and base64 encoding works perfectly without them.

When decoding back, you may pad a few `=` characters back just in case (always no more than 3, so I'd pad 3, but extra characters don't break anything:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode('aa')
'YWE='
>>> base64.b64decode('YWE==')
'aa'
>>> base64.b64decode('YWE===')
'aa'
>>> base64.b64decode('YWE======')
'aa'
>>>
```

On the other hand, putting `a` character, which is a valid b64 encoding character might ruin your decoded string:

```
>>> base64.b64encode('aa')
'YWE='
>>> base64.b64decode('YWEa')
'aa\x1a'
```